# How to make a post request to Wordpress to update images for employees via custom image field using Wordpress API

Tags: javascript, node.js, wordpress, api, post

I'm trying to figure out a way to update employee information on a Wordpress website. so far i have figured out how to update one user at a time by adding id on the endpoint. how can i update all users at once. I'm also using custom field via ACF

```
var axios = require('axios');

var data = JSON.stringify({
    "acf": {
        "twitter": "aaaaaaa",
      //"profile_picture": null,
    }
});

var config = {
    method: 'post',
    url: 'http://localhost:8888/sitename/wp-json/wp/v2/team/1111',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic dhhdsgbhadG',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    data: data
};

axios(config)
    .then(function(response) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

This code updates team member 1111 twitter url. so 2 questions

1. How do I do a post request for images.
2. How will i make this script update all employee profile pictures at once

the images are stored in a folder with each image url using their names

Comment: By images, I guess you mean users' profile pictures. Out-of-the-box WordPress uses "avatars" for these pictures. Look at the Settings -> Discussion panel in the dashboard. You can let users upload their profile pictures directly, but you need to install a plugin or two for that to happen. Figure out your use case a little better, then ask another question.  Oh, and you can't use the REST api to operate on more than one user at a time. It doesn't work that way.

Comment: well they dont have access to do that. their profiles are made from airtable. so what im doing is i am uploading image to Wordpress console. its thousands of images hence why im writing this script. essentially i want to remove the images from air-table and upload them to Wordpress console

Comment: Without a plugin add-on WordPress is only capable of showing gravatar-style avatars as user profile pictures. It can't show ordinary images. You need to choose, or write, a plugin that renders profile pictures from uploaded images. It will help if the plugin you choose implements a REST API. Then you need to, one at a time, upload each user's image and set the appropriate user metadata to point to it. If you have 1000 users you'll make at least 1000 REST API calls.

Comment: its not just for employee. we have thousand of user submitted images and thumbnails to our website as well those are the real issue